# Не пойму логику выброса исколючения в Task

Tags: c#, .net, task, .net-6

Проясните пожалуйста логику.
Тестовая платформа NET6. В тестовом методе Strat по факту не находит библиотеку.

```
await Task.Run(async () => await test.Start()); // Вызывает исключение
await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => await test.Start()); // не вызывает исключения
```

В чем разница? Я в Factory не могу обработать(получить) ошибки на выходе? Значит ли это, что стоит по возможности не использовать Factory?

Comment: Наведите в IDE мышкой на `Run` и `StartNew`, посмотрите, что возвращается. В первом случае - `Task<T>`, во втором - `Task<Task<T>>`. | Чтобы получить исключение во втором случае, добавьте `Unwrap()`. Или дважды(!) пишите `await`.

Comment: Просто используйте `Task.Run`, меньше путаться будете. Преимуществ у второго способа никаких, он является устаревшим. И нужно быть внимательным, отличать `Task` от `Task<Task>`.

Comment: Первый ответ просто в точку! Спасибо огромное. Буду знать.
Вообще у Factory вроде гораздо больше перегрузок метода. Иногда некоторые нужны.

Comment: Вы про перегрузки с `TaskScheduler`? Так есть же `SynchronizationContext`. Если код асинхронный, то второе будет весьма полезнее, потому что `await` все континуации закидывает в текущий контекст синхронизации, а там уж можно распихивать по потокам и приоритезировать как угодно. Если код синхронный, то без разницы, что использовать.